# Is hive.groupby.skewindata depend on hive.optimize.skewjoin?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

According to hive template :

`hive.optimize.skewjoin` : Whether to enable skew join optimization. The algorithm is as follows: At runtime, detect the keys with a large skew. Instead of processing those keys, store them temporarily in an HDFS directory. In a follow-up map-reduce job, process those skewed keys. The same key need not be skewed for all the tables, and so, the follow-up map-reduce job (for the skewed keys) would be much faster, since it would be a map-join.

`hive.groupby.skewindata` : Whether there is skew in data to optimize group by queries

But I don't understand whether 
`hive.groupby.skewindata` is dependent on `hive.optimize.skewjoin` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two properties deal with two different situations. You use hive.groupby.skewindata when there is a skew caused by group by clause. hive.optimize.skewjoin can be used when the data skew is caused by a join clause. The root cause is the same. Hive puts data with the same key to the same reducer.